# HTML 5 Rotating Banner?

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering if anyone could offer any advice. I'm an expert HTML / CSS coder...but I have little experience with HTML 5. I have read about the great things it can do and I want to learn it, but im not 100% sure of what I can do with it. I have read a lot of articles regarding HTML 5 but none of them go into enough detail about it to answer my questions.

Aside from making layout easier, can it do things like create a rotating banner? I need to take the banner on the main page of this site

www.newmarklearning.com

and make it ipad / iphone compatible. I know I could use Javascript and a host of other coding options, but i fugued this is a great place I could start messing with HTML 5.

Problem is in not really sure if thats the right technology to use. Can HTML 5 / CSS 3 handle such things or am i limited to Javascript / Ajax etc???

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be great.

Thanks

Craig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding animations, CSS3 offers you a lot of options. See e.g. [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_2dtransforms.asp) for more information on 2D Transforms. There exist 3D Transformations, too. However, only Webkit-based browsers support it right now. [This](http://www.css3.info/preview/) site also offers a list of CSS3's new features.

In your case, to have the banner animated, you would have to combine a transform with a transition property (the transition let's it animate, the transform only describes the targeted rotation/scale/skew). If you want a constant animation (not just once), there might be some Javascript necessary.

Well, apart from that, HTML5 offers you a lot more new features, like offline storage or other things. The only problem is that the user has to have a relatively new browser in order to support everything, which sadly isn't the case right now (I know several companies that still run Windows XP with some IE6 or 7 or something like that - any updates disabled :-/)

Edit: Oh, OK, I just took a look at your site. For such a "slideshow", at least a little bit of Javascript will be necessary, to store the current slide etc.. But every smartphone browser should support it without a problem

Comment: Thanks guys...thats what i figured. Javascript it is.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean the banner on the right? That changes on a timer, or when a number or arrow is clicked?
It would be easiest to recreate that with JavaScript.

Check out:
http://www.dhteumeuleu.com/

If you want some cool ideas